# Regex for stylelint selector-class-pattern rule

Tags: regex, stylelint

I'm trying to figure out the correct regex expression for the selector-class-pattern's I want to allow with stylelint

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/

I would only like to allow lowercase letters and numbers seperated by hyphons, and only allow underscores at the beginning.  So basically the following

```
.this-is-good
.also-good2
._this-works-too

.-not-this
.or-this-
.and_not_this
.OR-This
```

I've almost gotten it to work but can't get it to allow underscores only at the beginning of the pattern.

```
"selector-class-pattern": "^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$"
```

Comment: Maybe `^_?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$`?

Comment: @revo, that worked thanks.  Can you put it in a answer mark as asnwered

Comment: Mine's a little looser, allows single word classes (without dashes etc) and can't end with punctuation. ^([_a-z]+[\\-_a-z0-9]*[^\\-_]|[a-z]+)$

Answer (score 1):

### *Stylelint* [demo page](https://stylelint.io/demo/#N4Igxg9gJgpiBcID0AqABAcQPJYCJpSQB0A7AOgBcALASwGcBaehgcwmjWDUgBsIAneGn4woAbjQBfUmQCGPOhFbsoAJk7cIfQcNETp5APrVmAdwEBrRhXYbeAoSPFTSpVGgBCAQXyEZDEggKBhM6Oy0HXWcDMgEQ2kZw7Uc9F3JZEihDQIpjBKTIp30ZLAAlBgAVfK57HSK0kAAaEDoATxIKWQAPBHA6OibwCBIAMxoWXuBSNDQiEH4AVx4YOjmhKZIZmbmMnNkKGmGApQWSC0DTEjW0CkWYRumtneDF5eOGU-OIS+vbhfvHtsQAAjPhgCzvGAAWwADhRWr87g9Nk8htp3jQSAA3eQ0KAMKgwLqI-7IrazIZQqEwDqQ2HwkkAlFAsALOg2KEMGH8CAwmD8eHvKH0OiYlgMHH8BgjU5gA7DRlk1GwMA8WT8faHEgMUEQcHvKALGE8GhgfYwBis9kQTnc3n8g4rRWAikqtUa+Xa3X6wIMQ3G03mrk8vkCmhOhBoADaLpmfyZ5JmG0TqPGgRE1xjzJTFMgJDoMFZByxFv9JrNFBWDFMNGofpoIxG-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-7aq5YHQZgZYluCdyoe+hqMqBOG4nhPkkM+6GhCzFNVsTZMczmNMBEeknu20q0OQYZHoRbTsGbQPtsxmAde2elpbi-WiYFMEi6axgXTlrQmMZO+QYSoey23+Y5Ok9TNuxe-k4s6FhHt3JNObmIl0LhAAFEMHXDerSZzIFeTQ1K5k57mUz5mYhy4vLipZ+kz3FnUYH3DNIzt7T5FMWRWk7Q3OGNkBTZgOFNZ5xM5knZZ+gCkZKylOg3P0zOVljzmgTGOq0ZWStwtduOgRp0P6bTiPc-5BaqRbF2W65-sXS90SfaO1zpLNAtrjmPhTH5OYBaHt4fKq1D0JzvOJ5ASPo8YUUSBYN5xdn72XmH30S0yOJuWDmhiRhwfj7eAbTQiEzRcD2Q2-4dfN5jw-RMnMGtpfmBBqFeLVBSB2BMHWm69SJrl-tpf+qpAG7x1CAi0pExaYlyh-L+PAo4-yaFxRBfAd7imAQ9AIr8sFBxDhLHYeCt4MChEsA4xEsHwNRMQ5BZC0HKWXhaSBtDcH4O3mKfe7DCF-1kphPkJAgG8IwW-HBkZ6EiKYSwmgbDSIcKBP-e0ciUHkJXvdFe7814qI3gwmOykxEWgPpIhB0j9HyIoSYgRUCm4Um-qXUStRpSwSInsDWFioTQH5EJAWfjCRdHguPCxU8Z4ONRFEokxEaQsGoOvGcc4dG5kWi2P2rUtHuKEWHLWliRG5KNj3E2XQzZWTKT3cuNBK6UPZKIbu9sB722piwdMEtw5U0Fq0ZYJFgiQCpAuDmPc3aJg9lzSJ+TaQ3VrCsfhTB8ybmEVvXJcwmY2mDFhQUYCA7UMEdAxpKZVE7KSeSSmVzE51OTg05u9sgRmPbvs20VsBRpXrqiCu7I2k106TmbpQzG4DLLl4j+HdUZVPTiATEopYA2N3uI0iMk9QWFBSmWZ5J5ngpZGyZmtkaD2VQhQPOmNBlAgAHoAAooz2QAF49mZQwFlAAGBgABOHsKAACUDKGAcu5XynsABqQVKAAAkCL7mIupP0WQ+t14AFEuh8jlKIbgJKbRoDJbINAABHf4-BWhoEXjcCAaBIFoBAsCWQwJYmPT7tmIluZ9XfKOWeSl1LU4PMZWK9lrKeX8qFSKsV4apUyvlbcrYirtLKoLmqixmrtU1z1daKEaBXq-KtTeG1dqYAOpgE6l1Y83Vp0JQLUcHoiJOpQW41eiShCjRgHAhNcx63GR1BkcULbzmeOuQQuthkxxwX-o-IalDMGYo+Z-Cx3j1E8FYfY8dqpJ2NukTO5+fCKGLu2dY0hGKDZcV7VO3d0In58G1EOjxdDTqdsSZuoyV7sVor3nY6hUJugGS3Q24Y9UACMb7t0TmkX1QCCUb1DWPT47Sl6d2ft9E4U4UBLLEWGCwJWmRDnLhtidZDRxZ2KOoUe5dVjGDMLXZojdF6J1Ae1LOltlH20VMYaen92ju0gBIyx-dD7Skcdga+xjgG+0nOKTQi5rzEXeIVQnJOKdLlvJ2LCgTCLtKAqru02uMz-m9P6YG9TG9YUTPhQmh5yLNxfrPVi8EuLEz4q2LWriT5DwASAovBgZqgi3lHYwG6zYiqFiWbAcKAseJsUE5MudSjzEcZXbR9dEjosBNI4tfq6z2NeOo-Znj57RIxbgpZnLFDh1PrE0ujLvEiJ-pidJ8W9UuV1diyPC0Vb14JNqx5zL2pUIiA6ISAswUqGYts7ABDq60u8fa3BIbLZRtVhbVN6rL7862OKbs7iA2Pj8B4H5hYAX6pBd26VoiKy7q5eUcl6ju2qCq1gCwEQ6CgjGS-ui4r2k9oHSCVqLJQtd67cxLADon3IyqAFuJPS0lcZSgB+xDjoZdaqotKcLOwXay0G1OJcC+JhhAUnLt2HUkqy+f9eE0z2lg2stDZymNkbRVholdKuVSmakgBTejjVWqaq6rJ0W61NgS1lora65zvN+4C2WLvOsLL+RKHcrWE6jXCngKwaBgW6vA5y4yVQa4IHVBta4kahy+xnJdaE7dpL+XKl8fN02S3LlWPrKqzAzbu2neOSt51yX8TvjidEj7l36C3JKDPpNQGIgxg3x+tjCkoenIuSWyNlYq31nrc912nXohyUW5TxaDUu8LRYX2HENjd37c3Lz3ZQvfuS-6xkfyCv+d3ePoQ97-P9kzX8lOUC8rCWKPV6C7N+j6Wzc9+O-3thg-ssHtMaPzjJ7tsMZD9PvvFq5-jIX8JuT3Uvd8Z6v7aULSgX2ITwLHqWhqy3TWQ9E674RRfhpITkYykpr8BXuR3jV+ooLBQiQJSjLCyBUQoKK48hd7H6AHAFML-qXxgD0CA6RgAAs1+sB7cvo0GJE4okBW0J0+ago3Wge08fWokRB70Eob+F8se18J0vszWZyneamEcBWqWE+823YSaqIKmLy0Y0Kj45+emIKXYhmCckKNOQyi6cKXcYhXS7qg4AsCOAUVKG4wICwSkvmVEBcPACS+IJo7I68LEu2Kh+wQsGhSkRiIEFA28Wemy02FiNWphrMAMqhFhmhZeoYbei+2CduHauesMrh8M5h6hnhLe2E7elWLBomR+yhwRcQoRNAlhFo-md00B8Rqk8MW62cVO-ANK5Swahg9O0aEqzOpR-K7O8accPBQIPOaaHGGaAuUA3A4MaACOxa9qjqzqAeih-MQRWRcQEywImIPhVe-hK+iGqIKhwxox8M++I6kxLhgxUoMUcUmGtIsx148MtERwbiJ0Kh-keRBRaccwdOnKDO4qEawqLOjObOcanOPS3OJcvO6a-OOqLReI7RCR-AnRpa3RlasgcSfRnsmRNUcQhhu+8Wv+fhbaNeY6Ax4JIB9AUJf6vhsmixzhfGKh6uTBpErWYJbhp8NBMeV88eksiJRJQQaskOHGEyxoRIyxSJCMMAIMSgORjAJBHGvWTJbhQMrJoMHJXIgU6eY26J2eThcRlJ8M-JbJLMKMBSXJFIPJ2JPxLJcprMqMC0d6NJwSHGk000ywvJ8M+MXWQJT6Kpyhs4AoeGi4PygoaGogGGWGKsJUWk0xwO4oaRgW-GU0M0u20s4y5pPWQe5B2krpwEoEBOAe3JoZu2EZkJcK9kMJraS692aiHBO2fGCZKJSZ6JeWY+3GWZAsOZ8+8WCxG2gRokpZwQuJp+LW1wpu1Z8gqsxJ58pJcejIjwBgkgIAkgQAA) with exactly the rule that works for you:

```
"selector-class-pattern": "selector-class-pattern": "^([_a-z][a-z0-9]*)(-[a-z0-9]+)*$",
```

[image]